# This question is really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I asked this question: [Make multiple querys in the database, or process the data and make just one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954880/make-multiple-querys-in-the-database-or-process-the-data-and-make-just-one-quer)
And it got marked as a duplicate.

I asked a specific PHP question, and the one that is said to be a duplicate of is a general question.

So, is this really a duplicate?

Comment: Well the answers to the other question answer your question, so yes they are duplicates.

Comment: No, the other answers shows the time it takes to do a query, they do not state the time it takes to process a specific query string.

Comment: What is the difference between "doing a query" and "processing a specific query string"?  That sounds exactly the same to me.

Comment: The answer to "which is faster" questions is *always* "time it and find out".  Why don't you just time both the queries you came up with and find out?

Comment: The performance of SQL queries is related to the SQL database, not to PHP or whatever language is sending the query.

Comment: By proccess a query string I meant to create the string that I'll use for the query.

Comment: @Rafael then the fact that it's a sql string is irrelevant right? if that's the case you could have just use a sample string instead of a query string.

Comment: For almost all optimization questions, the answer is *It depends on your particular use case, data, and query. Run it both ways against your own conditions, time it, and use the one that you think is best as a result.* Asking *which is faster* is based on too many variables to which we don't have access. Learn to do your own benchmarks and figure it out. Once you've done that, you can ask specific questions about those benchmarks or the results you get. Broad, general *which is faster* simply isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of those cases in which the duplicate transcends the language that it's originally asked in.

Your question is asking this:

> Which is faster:  a single insert to the database per entry, or a single insert with multiple value statements per entry?

This [is well-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793209/1079354).  Hence, closing it as a duplicate was the correct action.

If you're concerned about the nuance of performance with your second example, *focus **only** on that second example.*  I did another scan to see if it really could be PHP-centric, but it reads like the above.

This is your opportunity to edit the question and demonstrate that there is no duplication between the two.  If you are worried about the performance of the string concatenation, you should be specific.  Otherwise, I'm inclined to agree with the dupe.